# Solving Maxwell equations on curved spacetime

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, metric-tensor, maxwell-equations

I have difficulties to understand how to solve the Maxwell equations on curved spacetime. I want to solve the equations in the weak regime $g_{\mu\nu}=\eta_{\mu\nu}+h{\mu\nu},~ h_{\mu\nu}\ll 1$ without sources $J_{\mu}=0$. I use $\eta_{\mu\nu}=\text{diag}(1,-1,-1,-1)$.

The Maxwell equations in curved spacetime are:

$F^{\mu\nu}_{~~~~~||\mu}=0 ~(*)$

$\epsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda\kappa}F_{\lambda\kappa||\nu}=0 ~(**)$

where $||$ means covariant derivative. In the following I focus on $(*)$. I can rewrite $(*)$ as:

$0=F^{\mu\nu}_{~~~~~||\mu}$=$F^{\mu\nu}_{~~~~~|\mu}+\Gamma^{\mu}_{\mu\rho}F^{\rho\nu}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{g}}\partial_{\mu}(\sqrt{g}F^{\mu\nu})$,

where I have used the definition of the Christoffel symbols $\Gamma^{\mu}_{\mu\rho}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{g}}\partial_{\rho}\sqrt{g}$ and $g=-\text{det}(g^{\mu\nu})$. 
Summarized I get

$\partial_{\mu}(\sqrt{g}F^{\mu\nu})=0,~~~ (***)$

I furthermore use the transverse traceless gauge

$h_{\mu\nu}=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0&0\\0&h_+&h_\times&0\\0&h_\times&-h_+&0\\0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$

and assume that $h_{\mu\nu}$ is a background field. The coupling to the Einstein Equations is neglected. I can expand

$g=1-h_+^2-h_\times^2+\mathcal{O}(h^4)$

I now can divide $F^{\mu\nu}$ in powers of $h$: $F^{\mu\nu}=F_{(0)}^{\mu\nu}+F_{(1)}^{\mu\nu}+\cdots$ and expand all fields in equation $(***)$

The zeroth order yields normal electrodynamics:

$\partial_{\mu}F^{\mu\nu}_{(0)}=0$

However the first order field strength tensor also yields normal electrodynamics:

$\partial_{\mu}F^{\mu\nu}_{(1)}=0$

$\textbf{Now comes my question}$

If I rewrite $(***)$ to

$\partial_{\mu}(\sqrt{g}g^{\mu\alpha}g^{\nu\beta}F_{\alpha\beta})=0,~~~ (****)$

and do the expansions I get non trivial first order equations for $F^{\mu\nu}_{(1)}$:

$\partial_{\beta}F^{\mu\beta}_{(1)}=-(\partial_{\nu}h^{\mu}_{~\alpha})F^{\alpha\nu}_{(0)}-\partial_\nu(h^{\nu}_{~\beta}F^{\mu\beta}_{(0)})-h^{\mu}_{~\alpha}\partial_{\beta}F^{\alpha\beta}_{(0)}$

How can this be? Does it have to do something with the choice of the system where we do the calculation? I am interested in the case that a gravitational wave hits the Earth. What would be the physical electromagnetic fields? Would they be components of $F^{\mu\nu}_{(1)}$ or components of $F_{(1)\mu\nu}$? I think this should not matter since we have to raise and lower the indices with $\eta$ in order not to change the order of the tensor!? My question also arises due to this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0807.0885.pdf). They solve my equation $(****)$ what is their equation (9) in the paper. However to get to the physical electromagnetic fields they say that one has to do another transformation, c.f., their equation (A.9)-(A.11). I simply do not understand this.

Comment: Where you have defined the expansion of $F^{\mu \nu}$ as an expansion in powers of h, I don't quite understand what you mean, since there is no $h$ multiplying the $F^{\mu \nu}_{(1)}$ term. Is it a power series in $det(h_{\mu \nu})$?

Comment: $F^{\mu\nu}_{(1)}$ has no definition when I do the expansion. It is the function that I am looking for. At the stage of the expansion just consider it as an expersiion which contains one $h$. If you look at the end result you can see that this makes sense

Comment: Before equation (48) they pointed out that "Any physical measurement by an observer in curved spacetime should be carried out in a local inertial frame, i.e., the observable quantities are the projections of the physical quantities
on to the four orthonormal bases $e^{\mu}_0, e^{\mu}_1, e^{\mu}_2,e^{\mu}_3$ carried by the observer. Therefore, the observable EM fields are $F_{\alpha \beta}=F_{\mu \nu}e^{\mu}_{\alpha}e^{\nu}_{\beta}$"

Comment: That's one point which I don't understand. Why do they chose these particular $e^{\mu}$'s? I tried to invert $g_{\mu\nu}$ to make the frame locally Minkowski, but that seems not to be what they mean?

Comment: @jojo123456 Probably they just try to solve equation $g_{ik}=\eta _{\mu \nu}e^{\mu}_ie^{\nu}_k$.

Comment: Have you looked at http://www.hep.princeton.edu/~mcdonald/examples/rotatingEM.pdf?

Comment: I will look into it